# Why does roaming setup not work? (Linksys WRT1200AC with OpenWRT and TP-Link EAP610)

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, wifi-configuration, openwrt, wireless-roaming

My understanding is that for roaming two access points only need (a) be connected to the same wired L2 network (b) have the same SSID (c) have the same security setting.

I am using a Linksys WRT1200AC and a TP-Link EAP610 but roaming does not work: Devices stay connected to the EAP610, even if I am standing right next to the Linksys. iPhones wouldn't even connect: "Unable to connect to this network". Even if I unplug the EAP, nothing changes. Only if I remove the wifi network profile completely from the client devices, re-connect and re-enter the password, devices can connect to the Linksys again.

These are the settings for Linksys WRT1200AC with OpenWRT:

[image]

And the settings for the TP-Link EAP610:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you perhaps select "WPA3 only" in the connection profile?

Comment: @u1686_grawity you mean on the client? No, I am not doing any explicit settings on the client